# Rewriting my app from ruby/rails to javascript/express. Will mongodb suit my needs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, node.js, express

My Rails 3 database schema.rb looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110504034934) do

  create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "ancestry"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["ancestry"], :name => "index_comments_on_ancestry"

  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "topic_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "topics", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

The only additions to this database would be user-related via openid. Can mongoDB handle this?

Comment: MongoDB should handle such stuff pretty easily. One thing to note though is the document structure, which very much depends on the usage and queries. You can directly translate tables to collection, but it would defeat the purpose of using MongoDB. One document oriented paradigm which could help is embedding comments in posts. Keep in mind that MongoDB has no joins.

Comment: Check out http://mongoosejs.com/ it's the most popular ORM for node.js.

Comment: also https://github.com/noblesamurai/noblerecord which is ActiveRecord adapted to Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MongoDB can handle this type of structure. Note that you may want to change the structure of your data. You may want to consider embedding `comments` inside of `posts`.

Also take a look at `topics`. If the topic name is unique (it probably is), then you may want to consider making it the `_id` in MongoDB.

If you're moving to Node / MongoDB, you'll want to check out mongoosejs.com. It's a simple ORM for MongoDB. It may help you model the data.

Comment: Basically, in plain English this is the structure: many comments belong to a post and a post belongs to only one topic. So I'm not sure if I should use topic as the id.

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule on modeling your data with MongoDB. In general, you store comments inside of the post. In general, comments are not very useful without the post. However, if you anticipate tens of thousands of comments, they may not all fit in the post. However, even though a post "belongs to" a topic, you do not want to model it this way. A topic will have too many posts to reasonably store.